# Sequential save with reference with $resource

Tags: angularjs, scope, resources

I am trying to save 2 records sequentially and use the id of the first record as a reference in second record. so here is what it looks like..

```
dept = {id: 1, name:"First"}
student = {name: "a", dept_id: 1}
```

now i have student form in which i can either select or create a new dept. 
my controller looks like this

```
.controller('StudentCtrl', ['$scope', 'Student', 'Department'], function($scope, Student, Department){

       $scope.saveStudent = function (){
           getDeptId($scope.deptName);
           var o = new Student({
               name: $scope.name,
               dept_id: $scope.deptId
           });
       }

       var getDeptId = function(name) {
          index= _.findIndex($scope.depts, {name:name})
           if(index === -1) {
             // new record
             Department.save({name:name}, function(d){
             $scope.deptId= d["id"]
             }) 
           }
           else{
            //existing record
           }
        }
});
```

but $scope.deptId is always null.

Please note I am a newbie in Angularjs and would appreciate any help. :D

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, your Department.save is probably async.

Can you try something like this (below)?

```
   .controller('StudentCtrl', ['$scope', 'Student', 'Department'], function($scope, Student, Department) {

   $scope.saveStudent = function () {
       // ** Pass a function as a promise for your getDeptId:
       getDeptId($scope.deptName, function() {
           var o = new Student({
               name: $scope.name,
               dept_id: $scope.deptId
           });
       });
   };

   var getDeptId = function(name, promise) {
      index= _.findIndex($scope.depts, {name:name});
      if(index === -1) {
         // new record
         Department.save({name:name}, function(d){
           $scope.deptId= d["id"];

           // ** Call the promise only when you receive you "id":
           promise();
         });
      }
      else{
        //existing record
      }

    };
    });
```

I don't know the rest of the code, but I think you should call this "promise" that I created according to your need. I just wanted to show you that you have to wait for "Department.save" to return from the server until you set dept_id.

I haven't tested as I'm a newbie as well. Hope it helps you! :)